# How to add navigation drawer above bottom navigation bar when using navigation drawer in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Activity consists of a bottom navigation bar and a fragment. The fragment contains a navigation drawer which I want to be visible above the bottom navigation drawer.

**What I have is this:**

[image]

**What I want to achieve is this**

[image]

**My fragment layout-**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/panels_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**My activity-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.harshitaneja.homie.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation_main"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout">
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am sorry if i have made any mistake while asking this question as this is my first question here. Thanks

Comment: Show your layout xml code

Comment: @Sony Added the layouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` into your `content_main`. so that your activity will contain only a view group and the fragment will contain the drawer and the bottomNavigationView like this

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <CoordintorLayout>
         <AppBarLayout>
         </AppBarLayout>
         <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

          <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
              android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
              app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_state_list"
              app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_state_list"
              app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items">

         </LinearLayout>
    </CooorDinatorLayout>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I thought of this. But it would require to add bottom navigation bar in every fragment. And if there is a change in the navigation bar it would have to be changed in all the fragments. Isn't there a cleaner solution?

Comment: You can make an extra layout for your navigation and include then where ever you want, just like you add the main content and add custom navigation if there is any change

Comment: I tried it. But because it was redrawing everything again when changing the fragments made it look less fluid. So I went the other way and added the navigation drawer to the main activity and now manipulate it through the fragments.
Anyways thanks a lot for your help.